# MVC FileStreamResult and handling other

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

FileStreamResult disposes the given stream at the end of write but I have some more items I need to dispose

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("url");
return File(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), mimeType);
```

how/where do I dispose `client` and `response`?

Edit: I tried `OnActionExecuted` but it runs before response ends and I don't know about the HttpClient but disposing `response` loses me access to the stream

Edit: I'm also looking for a general solution that applies to anything. The code sample is for `HttpClient` but it may also be `Process.StandardOutput` depending on case

Comment: using (var client = new HttpClient()) { }

Comment: and `response`?

Comment: Do not create/dispose an HttpClient per action, it's terrible for connection management and will fail under load.

Comment: The response does not need to be disposed, disposing the steam is the only part that matters.

Comment: HttpResponse has a RegisterForDispose method you can use.

Comment: Don't dispose `client`, put is somewhere you can re-use it and re-use it for the lifetime of your application. See [You're Using HttpClient Wrong and It's Destabilizing Your Software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). The MS docs are also now quite clear on this. Also note that the File result will take care of disposing the stream. You will get an exception if you try to put a using around the stream.