# Core 2.0 MVC - How to link to a dynamic PDF saved on the file system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.0 MVC project. One of my models has a NotMapped IFormFile field called PDFUpload that takes an upload and saves the file to a place on the file system outside of the root, that path is saved in the PDF field. When users hit a specific URL, the PDF needs to be displayed in the browser or downloaded. My Details.cshtml View currently just shows the path

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PDF)
```

How do I turn this into an actual link that will serve the file from a specific URL, and not show the path?

Update: Here is the working version

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(pdf))
{
    var stream = new FileStream(pdf, FileMode.Open);
    // send the file to the browser
    stream.Position = 0;
    //return File(stream,"application/pdf","filename.pdf") //- will force download
    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");//will display in browser        
}
```

Comment: In your controller don't use return view, instead user `return File(model.PDF, "application/pdf");` to display the PDF in browser or `return File(model.PDF, "application/pdf", "your file name.pdf");` to force download

Comment: mylee THANK YOU SO MUCH for that tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just make a controller action to serve up the file.  You will need some way to identify the file and use that identifier to locate it.  Something like this (I used a slug):

```
public IActionResult GimmeThePdf(string slug)
{
    string filePathToPdf = // look this up in a database given the slug, map the path, etc.
    // open the file for reading
    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filePathToPdf, FileMode.Open)
    {
        // send the file to the browser
        return File(stream, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
//generate the link, could also do this with tag helpers
@Html.ActionLink("download the pdf", "GimmeThePdf", "YourController", new {slug = Model.PdfSlug});
```

Which will generate something like this:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/YourController/GimmeThePdf?slug=...">download the pdf</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @Becuzz, that helped a lot. I was unable to get it to work with  using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filePathToPdf, FileMode.Open) and got the error ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file. file(stream). I removed "using" and it worked but Im worried that the stream isnt being properly closed after the return. Should I be?

Comment: @user6383418 I've run into that before.  Usually just solved it by using a MemoryStream and reading all the bytes and passing that into the File method.  As far as if your stream got disposed, no it didn't.  So now you are waiting on garbage collection / process reset / etc to release the hold on the file.  I'm not super familiar with the details on exactly what will happen when there, but it's better to make sure your streams get disposed properly.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add to @Becuzz Answer. I was having trouble disposing of my file and I found my answer here [MVC FileStreamResult and handling other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47350369/14655002)

```
public IActionResult GimmeThePdf(string slug)
{
    string filePathToPdf = // look this up in a database given the slug, map the path, etc.

    // open the file for reading
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePathToPdf, FileMode.Open);

    // Register this stream for disposal after response is finished.
    HttpContext.Response.RegisterForDispose(stream);

    // send the file to the browser
    //return File(stream,"application/pdf","filename.pdf") //- will force download
    return File(stream, "application/pdf");
}
```